# Magento Eliminate Credit Card Fields

Tags: php, magento, authorize.net

We have a Magento Pro 1.10.2 store accessing "incentive points" to be used like cash for products.  We've redirected the Authorize.net module to communicate with a website of ours instead of their credit card services.  This works great except that we need to remove the dialog boxes for credit card information from the frontend checkout page.  We've looked though onepage.phtml and form.phtml but are baffled.

All we really need to do is to make card type, card number, expire date, and CCV invisible but give them default values so that the verifyer doesn't complain (or just turn off verification).  We don't need these fields for the way that we are using the Authorize.net interface.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @

Frontend

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/form/ccsave.phtml
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/form/cc.phtml

Admin

/app/design/adminhtml/base/default/template/payment/form/ccsave.phtml
/app/design/adminhtml/base/default/template/payment/form/cc.phtml

I think it would be better if you create your own custom magento payment module see http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/